# Azure Cloud service IP restriction without redeploy

Tags: azure-cloud-services

Is there possibility to add IP Restriction for existing Azure Cloud Services:
https://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/services/cloud-services/?

Condition: Can't do deployment of a new package.

Here is a way but requires new deployment:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-startup-tasks-common#block-a-specific-ip-address

I tried this approach - but didn't work for me:
https://www.henrihietala.fi/apply-ip-restrictions-for-azure-cloud-service/

I connect RDP to WebRole and later configure IpSecurity in a Web.config but it also didn't work. Also reboot cleaned all setup done manually. 
I didn't find a place where package .cspkg is stored to add startup task&IpSecurity in a Web.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without deploying a new package.

You can achieve this with Azure Web Apps if you ever decide to go that route.

Comment: Till now I didn't find a way to do it. In App service there is [Ip restriction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions).
I am still waiting for an answer from the support, to ensure that it is not possible.

Comment: I got an answer from Support - they confirmed that it is not possible.